# Batchload with to many cronjobs at once = performance issue

Tags: java, cron, message-queue

Dear Stackoverflowers!

In our system we have around 100 customers importing more than 1000 documents each day. 
We import the documents to the database by setting up a cronjob for each customer which run every 5 minute and polls a sftp for new documents. Each customer have their own sftp site. We then have a batchload based on java, crawling on all these documents before they are imported into the database.

Basicly for each cronjob, a java instance will be created and eventually empty the memory since several cronjobs could be executed at once.
We always have to check if we need to order more memory each time we get a new customer.

I am not sure if cronjob is the most efficient solution for this environment. We could end up/we have ended up spending more money on upgrading the server than we should.

I was thinking maybe a Message Queue would be a better solution?

Comment: I think you should have one Java App, with scheduled jobs for each client, that checks your ftp sites for changes and uploads them back. Once they are in, one processing queue (yes you can use MQueue for that). Both parts can be easily multithreaded. You can independelty set the scheduler pool size and your procossors size to make the best use of your cores and work load.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But if I would use MQ, wouldn't I have the environment set up like this: Customer -> MQ -> Java App -> Database ?

Comment: Ah Ok. I thought you could not change the customer part and you are stuck with  ftp to pull the data. Ofcourse the way you described is the best.